# How to get result array in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of list of fruits

```
id  |  name  |  amount
----------------------
 1  |  banana|  $60
 2  |  kiwi  |  $20
 3  |  orange|  $10
 4  |  pear  |  $12
 5  |  orange|  $80
 6  |  banana|  $30
 7  |  kiwi  |  $70
 8  |  pear  |  $35
 9  |  banana|  $15
 10 |  mango |  $20
```

and mysql query:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d");
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fruits WHERE date_of_tr='$date'");
mysql_close();
```

So I would like to have the following result:

```
   id  |  name  |  amount
----------------------
 banana|  $105|  3  
 kiwi  |  $90|  2
 orange|  $90|  2
 pear  |  $47|  2
 mango |  $20|  1
```

Thank you

Comment: you should save data 60,20 not with dollar sign . this dollar sign use it in php. you should created column name like that `amount_dollar`

Comment: Shurely shome mishtake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
  SELECT name , sum(SUBSTRING_INDEX(amount, '$', -1)) amount ,count(*) counts 
  FROM fruits 
  GROUP BY name 
  WHERE date_of_tr= '$date'
  order by amount desc
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/758e7/23)

Answer (score 0):

Tend to get what you ask for around here ;-)

```
 SELECT name id
      , SUM(REPLACE(amount,'$','')+0) name
      , COUNT(*) amount
   FROM fruits f
  GROUP
     BY f.name
```